# error when reading asp.net membership tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net website that uses mysql for membership. the web app works well when i am connecting to mysql hosted on windows OS but throws an error due to table name (case-sensitivity) on Linux.

The error is not relavant to my tables, but it is related to internal MySQL adapter classes when calling to authenticate a user.

Here is the error:

Table '**dbname.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'dbname.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist

Given, i have aspnetusers table with lower case in my database. the error raises only when i change the host from mySQL on windows to Linux.

Here is the line of code that throws the exception:

```
public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
```

Also note, i don't have any membership tables in the asp.net web app since i am using the configs for (membership, role provider) to connect and authenticate users.

Any help is appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can re-map table names for identity and membership provider in asp.net by overriding the **OnModelCreation** method in **IdentityModels**.cs.

Here is the solution:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("aspnetusers");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("aspnetroles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("aspnetuserroles");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("aspnetuserclaims");
                modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("aspnetuserlogins");

}
```

You notice that explicitly set all standard asp.net membership table names to lower case as i have it in my database which was causing the issue.

Now i can connect, authenticate and manage membership from my existing web app that is connected to Linux based MySQL DB.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Follow a dynamic solution for all tables.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()) {
            entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Relational().TableName.ToLower();
        }

    }
```